# NSForegroundColorAttributeName doesn't work in Swift?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

In `viewDidLoad`, I have something like the following to add text attributes to a `UITextField`:

```
let textAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: 1.0
]

self.textField.delegate = self
self.textField.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes
self.textField.text = "Top text field"
```

All of these attributes seem to work properly, except `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`. This text appears transparent. Is this a Swift bug?

The text is being placed over an image in a `UIScrollView`. Text as it appears:

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Udacity's MemeApp!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From [Technical Q&A QA1531](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1531/_index.html):

> This is because the sign of the value for NSStrokeWidthAttributeName
>   is interpreted as a mode; it indicates whether the attributed string
>   is to be filled, stroked, or both. Specifically, a zero value displays
>   a fill only, while a positive value displays a stroke only. A negative
>   value allows displaying both a fill and stroke.

So with your setting

```
NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: 1.0
```

the font is stroked only and not filled, resulting in an "outline font". You'll want to set

```
NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: -1.0
```

instead so that the font is stroked *and* filled.

You can find that information also if you command-click on 
`NSStrokeWidthAttributeName` in Xcode to jump to the definition:

> NSNumber containing floating point value, in percent of font point
>   size, default 0: no stroke; positive for stroke alone, negative for
>   stroke and fill (a typical value for outlined text would be 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `NSAttributedString` with your text attributes and then set the `attributedText` property of the text field:

```
textField.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Top text field", attributes: textAttributes)
```

Comment: I've tried that. Same thing. Image added above to show how it appears.